# Defining which option returned by JSON is greater according to the combination of two data values

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, telegram, telegram-bot

In order for me to download an image published on a Telegram channel, I need this path:

```
var contents = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);
Logger.log(contents.channel_post.photo);
```

And the answer is:

```
[{
    "file_id":"AAAAA",
    "file_size":11111,
    "width":253,
    "height":320
},{
    "file_id":"BBBBB",
    "file_size":22222,
    "width":632,
    "height":800
},{
    "file_id":"CCCCC",
    "file_size":44444,
    "width":1400,
    "height":1100
},{
    "file_id":"DDDDD",
    "file_size":33333,
    "width":980,
    "height":750
}]
```

The user @Newbie told me to use `Math.max(width, height)` to be able to define which of the container has the highest quality image so that I can define in this call which `file_id` should i use for download:

```
contents.channel_post.photo[CONTAINER NUMBER].file_id
```

In this case the container would be number `3`. But I couldn't work with this `Math.max`, I need help to understand how my code should be to do this work.

Comment: You are not telling me where `e.postData.contains` comes from, you may be querying the wrong api. Or simply the message you are looking at is not a picture message.

Comment: Furthermore are you working in `javascript` or `java`? What is that Java style Log `Ljava.lang.Object;@1b9467cf` ?

Comment: Hi @Newbie I just updated the question again, ```Ljava.lang.Object``` is an answer that Google App Script gives and when I call the ```contents.channel_post.photo``` path then it delivers the values that are inside this object

Comment: @BrondbyIF Please check my solution when you have a moment

Answer (score 1):

To retrieve an image URL from a `Message` object from the [Telegram Bot Api](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api) you will need to:

- Retrieve a `Message` object (from any of the various APIs)
- extract `photo` field of type `PhotoSize[]` [Documented Here](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#photosize)
- when you choose a `PhotoSize` (in your case the biggest one) you have `file_id`
- the you need to pass `file_id` to `getFile()` [Documented Here](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getfile)
- it will return a `File` object [Documented Here](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#file)
- that can be then assembled in a URL like `https://api.telegram.org/file/bot<token>/<file_path>`

Comment: Hi @Newbie, when i get the value via ```var contents = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents)```   and extract the ```photo```value like```contents.channel_post.photo``` return ```{width=90.0, file_id=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX, height=51.0, file_size=1301.0, file_unique_id=YYYYYYYYYYYY}```, but in ```PhotoSize``` documentation it's saying that it returns thumbnail values, in this case it doesn't return the original value, could you help me understand?

Comment: And another question @Newbie is how will I choose the maximum size since the value is already stipulated in the photo text return?

Comment: I'm unable to follow you. Can you update your question with the entire Message JSON payload so we can understand what the issue is

Comment: Hi @Newbie i updated my question with your request

Comment: Hi @Newbie i find a solution to get the full image, ```contents.channel_post.photo[contents.channel_post.photo.length - 1];```, as it comes in a container with thumbnail, publication image and original image, you need to get the option with the largest size. I updated my question, it would be interesting for you to adjust it and add this item of length so that in the future those who need it will also understand it better.

Comment: As i stated you should get **"in your case the biggest one"**. It does not necessary mean the last one (length - 1) you should first sort the list according to Math.max(width, height)

Comment: Hi @Newbie Could you demonstrate in your answer how this should be done? A more complete example to make my understanding easier, I read about ```Math.max``` but if I need to choose which position to use before making the call, how will it parse? I'm sure more people will be interested, because in the other questions nobody gave this ```Math.max``` tip, your answer would be very complete and usual.

Answer (score 1):

Is the image quality not already determined by the `file_size` property? It appears as the resolution increases (`width * height`), so does the `file_size` and thereby the quality as well. For this, check my first solution above.

If instead, you want to find the highest quality image based on a ratio comparing `width * height` and `file_size` to find the average `file_size` in bytes per pixel (not recommended), please check my second solution below:

### Finding the largest image

This solution sorts the returned array of image data by comparing their resolution (`width * height`) and then takes the first (largest) image from the newly sorted array.

```js
const contents = {}; contents.channel_post = {}; contents.channel_post.photo = [
  { file_id: "AAAAA", file_size: 11111, width: 253, height: 320 },
  { file_id: "BBBBB", file_size: 22222, width: 632, height: 800 },
  { file_id: "CCCCC", file_size: 44444, width: 1400, height: 1100 },
  { file_id: "DDDDD", file_size: 33333, width: 980, height: 750 }
];

const largestImage = contents.channel_post.photo.sort((a, b) => (b.width * b.height) - (a.width * a.height))[0];

console.log(`The largest image's file_id is ${largestImage.file_id}, which contains ${largestImage.width * largestImage.height} pixels (${largestImage.width}×${largestImage.height})`);
```

### Finding the highest quality image (per pixel)

If you are specifically trying to determine the actual "quality" of the image regardless of resolution, the closest you could get with the data provided would be to divide the `file_size` by the total pixel area to determine the average `file_size` in byte per pixel.

By this logic though, the highest quality image would actually be `"AAAAA"` which I doubt is what you are going for, so you should probably use the first solution I provided, which returns the largest image.

It's worth noting that because image compression algorithms are quite advanced these days, using a formula like this to determine quality per pixel is hardly reliable as it is, so I do recommend using the first solution.

```js
const contents = {}; contents.channel_post = {}; contents.channel_post.photo = [
  { file_id: "AAAAA", file_size: 11111, width: 253, height: 320 },
  { file_id: "BBBBB", file_size: 22222, width: 632, height: 800 },
  { file_id: "CCCCC", file_size: 44444, width: 1400, height: 1100 },
  { file_id: "DDDDD", file_size: 33333, width: 980, height: 750 }
];

const calcImageQuality = ({ file_size, width, height }) => file_size / (width * height);
const highestQualityImage = contents.channel_post.photo.sort((a, b) => calcImageQuality(b) - calcImageQuality(a))[0];

console.log(`The highest quality image's file_id is ${highestQualityImage.file_id}, which contains ${calcImageQuality(highestQualityImage)} bytes per pixel on average`);
```

Comment: Hello again my friend, soon I will sit in front of the computer and put your indication into practice!  off topic: when you have time for that other question about Booyah, the points are saved for when you can choose to activate my Bounty.  haha

Comment: @BrondbyIF I knew your username looked familiar! Remind me again what the other question was… was it getting the other feature like bulk unfollow working?

Comment: Haha. I'm from that question we talked via Telegram and we made a video call to show you that even activating the code, it reached 100% but did not generate the expected result in any of the options that were created. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69076135/script-runs-smoothly-from-start-to-finish-but-the-expected-result-doesnt-happe

Comment: The question as it remained unanswered for a long time, it was deleted, but I created it again.

Comment: @BrondbyIF I'll try to take a look next week

Answer (score 0):

you can find highest quality image like this:

```
Math.max.apply(Math, array.map(function(o) { return o.width * o.height; }))
```

Comment: Hi mate, how would I insert my call into what you indicated taking into account that I need to make it read the values ​​to generate the array based on each of the blocks in the container?  Sorry for my lack of knowledge, but I couldn't understand.